# Python NumPy, can't create array of items array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a NumPy dataset with sentence IDs and **descriptions** values. I would like to create an **ordered** list in my desired format which is...  `[['value'], ['value']]` containing just description values. The order of the new list must stay the same as the original so I can match them back to the IDs later.

My issue is that I can't achieve the desired format for the new list instead of  `[['value'], ['value']]` I get `['value', 'value']`, why?

This is what I have tried:

**Original input data:**

```
[
[UUID('11ea1bca-eb95-4dc8-8cb9-c7d70a806679') 'the quick brown fox']
[UUID('339619ab-bd17-401f-82c8-a927145d52cf')' jumps over the lazy dog']
]
```

Created a new array to store just the description values:

```
description = np.array([description[1] for description in chunk])
```

However, this gives me the following output:

```
['the quick brown fox','jumps over the lazy dog']
```

**My desired output is:**

```
[['the quick brown fox'],[jumps over the lazy dog']]
```

How can I achieve my desired output keeping the original order?

- Using Python 3.8
- The original list is from `np.array_split(book_information, chunk_size)` which I loop over in chunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the additional dimension when defining your array: `description = np.array([[description[1]] for description in chunk])`.

Comment: Seem like I was not far off, Thank you! Will the order in which they are added stay the same? i.e I can be assured that the first ```['the quick brown fox']``` in the new list will be the same as the first in the original?

Comment: Yes, the order won't be changed: this comprehension is equivalent to a `for` loop that would go over the elements of the chunk in order, and appending them to the end of `description` as it goes.